# Selecting vertices that are visible from a particular position

Tags: three.js, autodesk

how to determine which vertices of buffer geometry are visible from a particular position in the scene?
I am using Autodesk view and data api and raytracing doesn’t seem to work.
The purpose is to apply functions to only parts of 3D objects that is visible to viewpoints/vectors located along a line.

Any help is appreciated

bellow is code sample:

```
var origin = new THREE.Vector3(1, 2, 3);
            var direction = new THREE.Vector3(3, 4, 7);
            var sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xff0000 });
            sphereMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide; 
            viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial('adn-material-vertex', sphereMaterial,true);
            var directionSphere = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(2, 20), sphereMaterial);
            viewer.impl.scene.updateMatrixWorld();
            var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(origin, direction.normalize());
            var intersect = raycaster.intersectObject(directionSphere, true);
             console.log("Intersect is: " + intersect); // returned intersect is empty
             //I also tried: intersectObjects with ray of objects and the result is the same
```

Comment: Dont know what is the meaning of vectors of 3D object.

Comment: vertices of the bufferGeometry

Comment: Cant be done efficiently just with CPU. The GPU have dedicated resource (Z-buffer) for this task. Perhaps if you show what you intend to use this for there might be solutions.

Comment: I am building an app that assess the geometry of group of buildings according to a viewer who moves along a particular line in the scene. I need to apply functions to only vertices that are viewable from that line. my idea, which may not be the best approach since I am new to coding, is to create a sphere mesh out of every vertex and raycast towards it from points along the line to check whether it is visible or not.

Comment: I dont think that would work because you could have a triangle in between the buildings and the viewer and your raycast may miss all 3 sphere mesh of the triangle. What you want could be done by reading back the value of the depth buffer of the rendered scene and compare that with the vertex you are interested in. However, I dont know how to do this with three js.

Comment: You might be able to brute force it by doing a ray cast to every vertice you are interested in. You may or may not need to first merge the geometries into one depending on how three js implements the raycast.

Comment: each time I do ray cast, only targeted vertex is converted to sphere mesh. Does this work?

Comment: You shouldnt need to convert vertex into sphere mesh at all. What ray cast does it that it goes through a mesh and returns the intersection points between the ray and the mesh. So to determine if a vertex is visible, you just have to cast a ray from the viewer position to the vertex position and see if the first intersection point is at the position of the vertex.

Comment: That is better. The problem is that raycaster.intersectObject(directionSphere, true); is not returning anthing